# How to space carve in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

This question is likely to be more about the right terminology and subjects to search for more than anything else. It feels like a simple enough concept to the point where tools should be available in Python/NumPy to do it, but I just have no idea what to look for.

I recently watched a [video on Space Carving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGs90KF4oTc) and I would like to implement the basic concept using video game sprites to attempt voxelizing them. I have sprites of characters from 8 equally spaced angles (front on, camera 45 degress right, fully right, back, etc.)

I haven't found a library dedicated to this concept, but I *think* it should be fairly simple to implement. My thinking is I can make a 3D array that is the max size of the sprite in all dimensions that is a solid block of "clay". Then I need a 2D representation of that 3D array at each rotation angle. For each pixel in that representation I need to be able to iterate down into the 3D array each block that a "laser" fired from that position would hit.
The first step would be removing the clay where the sprite is just alpha layer, (aka setting a bool to false). The next would be "painting" the shape where possible.

The problem is I just have no idea what mathematical or programmatic terms are associated with these concepts. I could get so far as to make a 3D block of clay. But how do I get 2D representations of a 3D array at several rotated angles about one axis that I can essentially fire lasers at?

Comment: **projection** = 2D representations of a 3D array at several rotated angles about one axis. maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry+projection+3d